# How to make Java ignore escape sequences in a String?

Tags: java, string, blob

I am writing a Java code to read Blob objects from an Oracle database table.

I need to retrieve the blob objects and store them into a String for further processing.
I convert the blob objects contents to String by this :

```
java.sql.Blob blob = rs.getBlob(i);
columnValue = new String(blob.getBytes(1l, (int) blob.length()));
```

However when I try to parse the resultant string, I get errors which say **"Not a valid escape sequence"** because apparently the Blob data consists of some data like **\x, \i** or something !

Is there a way to make **Java ignore these escape sequences** and make it to just consider the string with its contents as it is (i.e Strings containing \x, \i etc.) ?

Comment: The problem not *not* as expected. Escape sequences *only* have meaning in string literals. More likely the blob is *invalid* for the encoding (use the `new String` which takes an explicit encoding and choose the encoding as appropriate).

Comment: If you have non-ascii data in the blob, then pass the encoding while converting to string

Comment: @sudsomg The issue more sinister than that -- without an explicit encoding `new String` is system-dependent and non portable in which encoding it will try.

Comment: Is this genuinely *text* data to start with? If it's not, you shouldn't be converting it into a string. (And if it is, why is it in a blob?) You talk about trying to *parse* the resultant string - what sort of parsing are you talking about?

Comment: @Jon.. I dont know the type of data it contains.. I just want to convert it into a string and see its contents .... I am not using any special parsing tehnique. It was just a work i used !!!

Comment: @pst.. If that is the case, what should i do to see the blob contents as a string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by "parse" you mean something related to regex, because otherwise storing these values in a string will work fine - the escape sequences are useful only for string literals and regexes.

Anyway, [`StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) should do what you want (it's from commons-lang)

Apart from that - you should use `java.sql.Clob` for textual data.

Comment: Yes.. I need to make sure these escape sequences are dealt with before using the string so that no problems occur... I tried getting the class u mentioned but it is not working..

Comment: did you download commons-lang?

Comment: Yes.. i did it and i included them in my project.. But not working !!

Comment: _how_ it is not working? Not adding slashes? throwing exception? Be more specific. And show the piece of your code that fails

Comment: It is not working.. It still shows the same exception.. "Not a valid escape sequence" .. i called escapeJava from StringEscapeUtils with the columnValue after the code i have given in question...

Comment: @Bozho.. Sorry.... escapeJava has been working the whole time.. I found another thing wrong with the code.. I thought the error was because of this calls.. Turns out it isnt so... Thanks...

Comment: very helpful, thanks @Bozho!  The link is broken though.  I found the API here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with "\x" escape sequences. (These escape sequences only have meaning in string literals -- they have *nothing* to do with `new String`. The escape sequences found in regular expressions are just an interpretation of a string.)

The problem is that the blob contains data which *is invalid* for the given encoding. From the [`new String(byte[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d%29) documentation:

> **The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified.** The CharsetDecoder class should be used when more control over the decoding process is required.

Also do note that `new String(byte[])` *should not be used* because (also from the documentation):

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes **using the platform's default charset.**

I suspect thus that either

1. The blob data used is outright invalid and/or;
2. The "default charset" does not match the encoding of the supplied bytes

Happy coding

Comment: So that means that I need to know the encoding of the Blob to get the data right ? Is there no way to do without this ?

Comment: @Shyam That is the best way, yes. Some CharsetDecoders can (in theory) auto-detect a charset and a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) could be used (which is essentially just storing the particular Unicode encoding "type" as part of the encoded data). It might even be possible to use a try-X-and-if-that-fails-try-Y approach, but all of this really comes down to the particular requirements at hand. Do double check the blob data first though, it may be a really trivial error such as skipping one byte when two should have been skipped ;-)